# fractional coordinates, in particular to vertically center an object, in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I use this css to vertically center things inside their parent:

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

This does the trick, but in chrome the horizontal lines of the border (for example) are sometimes blurred, because of the fractional coordinate, due to the division by 2 of the parent dimensions.

I have read that a possible solution could be to add:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

to the parent, but i don't see any effect.

Is there a real solution without using js to round the coordinates?

I made this [very simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1mzew5q/) to show what i mean, i put a hard coded fractional coordinate to force the problem. Please use chrome, for example Safari doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using a borderless wrapper, which center's using translate and then have a child with the border?

Comment: i am not sure i got the point, any child would still have a fractional coordinate, i am afraid, wouldn't it?

Comment: Very right :) ... don't know until one tried, deleted it

Comment: Browsers are currently very inconsistent when it comes to sub-pixel rendering... Is there a reason you cannot use js? It might be the simplest solution at this point.

Comment: @mhatch, I have a web application developed for safari that now I need to convert also for chrome, this is one of the few issues I found. To use js means to add js logic and call a function to manually center elements whenever the browser is resized, i can do this of course, but a pure css solution mean also to avoid documentation revision and specific tests for this new functionalities

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543142/css3-transformation-blurry-borders

Comment: May I ask how often you have encountered this and why not use another method which will not give you this issue in the first place?

Comment: See the answer to mhatch, that's the reason. I have already developed a simple solution in js that works, but this would mean to write down more documentation and to perform test I am trying to avoid